# Website not accessible from outside of my house, but works fine on my home network

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, dns, bind

I have a Ubuntu server 20.04, I cannot access my cloud system outside of my house, I am running bind9, apache2, php, MariaDB, I use Cloudflare and I have ipv6 enabled on my router,
`ip address`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:23:24:08:58:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.8/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp0s25
       valid_lft 84322sec preferred_lft 84322sec
    inet6 2604:99c0:8:2f0f:223:24ff:fe08:581f/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 43200sec preferred_lft 27000sec
    inet6 fe80::223:24ff:fe08:581f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Cloudflare DNS
[image]
Router Page
[image]

I will give any logs, files, that you need
Thank you!

Comment: Do you need my Bind9 confs?

Comment: Is your router configured to do port forwarding?

Comment: yes it is, do you want that screenshot?

Comment: I need to get this fixed by next week

Comment: This is almost definitely related to your router's firewall rather than Ubuntu.  If you're trying to access your server via IPv4, you need to have port forwarding set up.

I'm not super familiar with IPv6 but I would have expected your server's IPv6 /64 prefix to match your router's IPv6 prefix?  Regardless, you'll need to do whatever to get IPv6 traffic allowed through your router/firewall as well.

Comment: @BrianTurek, I am in the DMZ, I have port forwarding correctly, It just stopped one day. I  Nor my ISP changed anything

Comment: Are you trying to access this via IPv4 or IPv6?  If IPv6, your addresses don't match between Cloudflare and your gateway screenshot.

Comment: @BrianTurek If I use the IPv6 from my router, it gives me the router login screen! not my website.

Comment: Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I need to get this working!